# Why my Mono should be subscribed while another case it runs correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

on this code, orderRepository.save(orders) is not working until i subscribe it. But i have called subscribe from my RestController.

```
@Service
public class CompleteOrderCommandImpl implements CompleteOrderCommand {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Override
    public Mono<Boolean> execute(CancelOrderCommandRequest request) {
        return orderRepository.findById(request.getOrderId())
            .flatMap(this::changeToCancel)
            .map(order -> true);
    }

    private Mono<Orders> changeToCancel(Orders orders) {
        orders.setStatus(StatusEnum.COMPLETED.toString());
        return orderRepository.save(orders);
    }
}
```

i have no idea why this happens while another case like this. restaurantRepository.save(restaurant) run without subscribe. because it is (subscribe) called in RestController.

```
@Service
public class ApprovePendingRestaurantCommandImpl implements ApprovePendingRestaurantCommand {

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;

    @Override
    public Mono<RestaurantResponse> execute(ApprovePendingRestaurantCommandRequest request) {
        return restaurantRepository.findById(request.getRestaurantId())
            .flatMap(this::changeRestaurantStatus)
            .map(this::constructResponse);
    }

    private Mono<Restaurant> changeRestaurantStatus(Restaurant restaurant) {
        restaurant.setStatus(true);

        return restaurantRepository.save(restaurant);
    }

    private RestaurantResponse constructResponse(Restaurant restaurant) {
        RestaurantResponse response = new RestaurantResponse();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(restaurant, response);

        return response;
    }
}
```

this is my controller

```
@PostMapping("/api/merchant/orders/{orderId}/complete")
public Mono<Response<Boolean>> completeOrder(Authentication authentication, @PathVariable String orderId) {
    return commandExecutor.execute(CompleteOrderCommand.class, constructCancelOrderCommandRequest(authentication, orderId))
            .map(ResponseHelper::ok)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
}

@PostMapping("/api/admin/restaurant/{restaurantId}")
public Mono<Response<RestaurantResponse>> approvePendingRestaurant(@PathVariable String restaurantId) {
    return commandExecutor.execute(ApprovePendingRestaurantCommandImpl.class, constructApprovePendingRestaurantCommandRequest(restaurantId))
            .map(ResponseHelper::ok)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
}
```

Comment: can you please post your controller code too .. for both the cases

Comment: i have added it

Comment: can you provide `constructApprovePendingRestaurantCommandRequest` and `constructCancelOrderCommandRequest` body?

Comment: Hi, I haven't been coding Java for a while but seems like both commandExecutors are not provided with the implemented class `CompleteOrderCommand.class` vs `ApprovePendingRestaurantCommandImpl.class`. Does this make any difference for the code execution?